# Changing text color in InputMethodeService

Tags: android

I want to change color of entering text by soft keyboard
it possible with `InputConnection`
I made `BaseInputConnection` individual:

```
public class k extends BaseInputConnection{
    Keying ke;
    public k(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(targetView, fullEditor);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    }
```

But in the class that extends `InputMethodService` I can't create the object. Because the `BaseInputConnection` requires a `View` and a `boolean` in the constructor.

How can I use that class in `InputMethodService` and I control in attribute it.
Can any one help me and provide some code advise ?

Comment: please any one answer me